# Do I need a custom payment method for a third party that handles Credit Card payment? Or is there something already provided by Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I'm using a third party payment gateway that I forward the user to after checking out so that he can enter his credit card info. The gateway then later provides a callback to our server regarding the status of the payment.

What do I need to set the payment method as, in the order?
`setPaymentMethod('......')`;

Is there a default one for such a scenario? Or do I need to make my own, custom payment method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento provides PayPal, Authorize.net by default. But, if you want to use any other third-party Payment method, then you need to use a separate module for Sure!

Comment: I see. Yes, I need to use another third party one. Any good tutorials on how to do it?

Comment: No exact tutorial is available, but you need to have api from Payment Method provider and credentials. You need to redirect the customer at Payment method providers page after they select your custom payment method.

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides payment integration with PayPal, Braintree, and Authorize.Net payment service providers. But for your case, as you need a third party integration that handles credit card payment, you surely have to create custom module i.e separate module surely.

And Magento's recommendation is to create integration with other payment providers, using [Magento payment provider gateway.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-gateway-intro.html)

For more details, you can find [this Magento Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/payments-integrations/base-integration/integration-intro.html).